# GetTextExtentPoint32 with horizontal tab in string

Tags: winapi

I'm using `GetTextExtentPoint32` to calculate the width and height of a string with a certain `HFONT`. My code looks like:

```
SIZE size;
HDC hdc = GetDC(handle);
SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, boost::nowide::widen(text).c_str(), static_cast<int>(boost::nowide::widen(text).length()), &size);
ReleaseDC(handle, hdc);
//using size.cx, size.cy as size
```

This works well most of the time, except if the string contains a horizontal tab (with character literal "\t"). While the documentation for [GetTextExtentPoint32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144938(v=vs.85).aspx) states:

> GetTextExtentPoint32 doesn't consider "\n" (new line) or "\r\n"
>   (carriage return and new line) characters when it computes the height
>   of a text string.

There is nothing said about "\t" (horizontal tab), so I'm wondering if this is the expected behavior of `GetTextExtentPoint32` or if I'm missing something here?
Is there another way to get the text extent of a string with a certain `HFONT` (without introducing dependencies to Gdiplus for `Graphics.MeasureString`)?

Comment: Naturally it cannot interpret `\t` because there is no parameter that specifies where the tab stops are. Try `TabbedTextOut`.

Comment: *"I'm wondering if this is the expected behavior"* - Hard to answer, since we don't know, what *"this"* is.

Comment: @IInspectable "_This_" is referring to the behavior that the returned width from GetTextExtentPoint32 is less than the actual width the string is occupying on the screen (i.e. as text on a static control).